# Dynamically adding SVG with clipping path

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm trying to add an SVG path that's clipped, with Javascript, but some of the pieces (specifically, the clipPath) aren't working. What am I doing wrong?

Here's a comparison [Codepen](https://codepen.io/jraynolds/pen/JaMBxy): working HTML version on the right, failed .js version on the right.

The relevant code:

```
var fieldShield = function() {
    var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
    svg.setAttribute("style", "height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute;");
    var clipPath = document.createElement("clipPath");
    clipPath.id = "fieldClip";
    svg.appendChild(clipPath);
    var fill = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
    fill.id = "fieldFill";
    fill.setAttribute("x", "0");
    fill.setAttribute("y", "0");
    fill.setAttribute("width", "450");
    fill.setAttribute("height", "450");
    clipPath.appendChild(fill);
    var path = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
    path.id = "fieldShield";
    path.setAttribute("d", "m395,20c0.910,57.6 0.857,115 0,173-0.833,55.5-3.60,98.8-28.5,133-29.9,40.8-79.8,70.2-144,99.2-64.2-28.9-114-58.4-144-99.2-24.9-33.9-27.6-77.2-28.5-133-0.857-57.6-0.910-115 0-173z");
    path.setAttribute("style", "stroke: white; stroke-width: 3;");
    svg.appendChild(path);
    var use = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "use");
    use.className = "divisions";
    use.setAttribute("clip-path", "url('#fieldClip')");
    use.setAttribute("xlink:href", "#fieldShield");
    use.setAttribute("fill", "red");
    svg.appendChild(use);

    console.log(svg);

    document.getElementById("svgHolder").append(svg);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of your problem is using deprecated [`xlink:href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href) attribute on `<use>`.
Consider using `href` instead:

```js
var fieldShield = function() {
 var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
 svg.setAttribute("style", "height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute;");
  
 var clipPath = document.createElement("clipPath");
 clipPath.id = "fieldClip";
 svg.appendChild(clipPath);
  
 var fill = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
 fill.id = "fieldFill";
 fill.setAttribute("x", "0");
 fill.setAttribute("y", "0");
 fill.setAttribute("width", "450");
 fill.setAttribute("height", "450");
 clipPath.appendChild(fill);
  
 var path = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
 path.id = "fieldShield";
 path.setAttribute("d", "m395,20c0.910,57.6 0.857,115 0,173-0.833,55.5-3.60,98.8-28.5,133-29.9,40.8-79.8,70.2-144,99.2-64.2-28.9-114-58.4-144-99.2-24.9-33.9-27.6-77.2-28.5-133-0.857-57.6-0.910-115 0-173z");
 path.setAttribute("style", "stroke: white; stroke-width: 3;");
 svg.appendChild(path);
  
 var use = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "use");
 use.className = "divisions";
 use.setAttribute("clip-path", "url('#fieldClip')");
 use.setAttribute("href", "#fieldShield");
 use.setAttribute("fill", "red");
 svg.appendChild(use);

// console.log(svg);

 document.getElementById("svgHolder").append(svg);
}

fieldShield();
```

```css
body {
  background: #aaa
}
```

```html
<div id="svgHolder"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You’re already using [`Document.createElementNS()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS) to correctly namespace the elements, but you also need to use [`Element.setAttributeNS()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttributeNS) when setting namespaced attributes.

In your example, this affects the following line:

```js
use.setAttribute("xlink:href", "#fieldShield");
```

The browser treats `xlink:href` as a single plain attribute, not an attribute with a specified namespace. Instead, you should use the `NS` version of this function to specify the `xlink` namespace:

```js
use.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "href", "#fieldShield");
```